# Adding Bootstrap to Angular 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angular, frontend

I am trying to add Bootstrap to my Angular app. I am new to this and although following the required steps I am having problems getting the bootstrap installed.

1. I did all the necessary steps from installing Angular cli, ng new first-app and ng serve.
2. I opened the vs code terminal and tried installing bootstrap using

   npm install bootstrap --save
3. Then adding this in the style.css

   @import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"

But still when I click on the link hovering over the above piece of code it says unable to locate file and prompts for creating a file with this path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to add the styles from bootstrap there is a property in the angular.json file that allows you to include it in the build.

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "projects": {
    "yourproject": {
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "options": {
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            ]
          },
        ...
```

See: https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#styles-and-scripts-configuration

Comment: Do we need to mention the JS file as well for Bootstrap in angular.json

Answer (score 2):

Add the below line in the `style.css` file which is present under the `src` folder inside the project.

```
@import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

Bootstrap isn't TypeScript code, so you don't import it as such.  Instead, it is CSS code, and thus you want to import it in your `index.html` file as a `

Here's how I import boostrap in my apps -- the below goes into the `<head>` tag of `index.html`

```
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
/>
```

Doing this then allows me to use Bootstrap within any of my code templates.

BTW, that code will link to the 4.3.1 version -- if you want to link to a different version, you can go to https://getbootstrap.com/ and get a "fresh" link -- the site is very helpful in getting you going with the CDN links.

But I see that you want to import it into your styles.css file, so you'll likely have to use a relative path, probably something like:

```
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
```

Comment: or can be imported in the styles array from angular,json file like so: `node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css`. in Angular is the common way to import it.

Answer (score 0):

An easy method to add bootstrap is by using Angular CLI(npm install).

From the command line interface install bootstrap and references it in angular.json

```
npm install bootstrap --save
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add bootstrap@3.x  || Here is the procedure.

Step 1. Install bootstrap. Run this command in your terminal.

```
npm install bootstrap@3.3.7
```

Step 2. Install Jquery. Run this command

```
npm install jquery
```

Step 3. Then, go to the **angular.json** file

```
...
        "styles": [
          "src/styles.css",
          "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
          "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        ]
...
```

Step 4. Don't forget to restart your app.